# How to add bootstrap 4 dropdown menu in Kendo UI Angular 2 grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

It seems that Kendo UI Angular 2 grid does not work well when I have Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu in the column.

To be very clear...

I have a requirement to display dropdown menu (using Bootstrap 4) in Kendo (Angular 2) Grid when user clicks on hyperlink in the grid cell (similar to right/left click context menu). So I have used Kendo Grid's Cell Template to show the link in the grid cell that shows the dropdown menu upon clicking (see code sample attached). Issue is that the link shows and clicking on it shows the dropdown menu as well, but the menu gets hidden inside the row height

View the plunker example live-test here: http://plnkr.co/edit/UuTGO4WWgMwIY9IPNGEj?p=preview

Code extract:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/npm/node_modules//@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css" />
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.11/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

    <!-- Example-specific styles -->
    <style>
      html, body { overflow: hidden; }
      body { font-family: "RobotoRegular",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; }
      my-app { display: block; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; min-height: 80px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 30px; }
      my-app > .k-loading { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
      .example-wrapper { min-height: 280px; align-content: flex-start; }
      .example-wrapper p, .example-col p { margin: 0 0 10px; }
      .example-wrapper p:first-child, .example-col p:first-child { margin-top: 0; }
      .example-col { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; }
      .example-config { margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 20px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03); border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08); }
      .event-log { margin: 0; padding: 0; max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; list-style-type: none; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08); background-color: #fff; }
      .event-log li {margin: 0; padding: .3em; line-height: 1.2em; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08); }
      .event-log li:last-child { margin-bottom: -1px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

  </body>
</html>
```

I would highly appreciate if anyone helps me to resolve this.

Comment: That link will probably be dead in short order, making this question less useful for others over time. Can you expand on what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you got?

Comment: Included the code sample, links may die.

Comment: I have a requirement to display Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu in Kendo (Angular 2) Grid

Comment: I have a requirement to display dropdown menu (using Bootstrap 4) in Kendo (Angular 2) Grid when user clicks on hyperlink in the grid cell (similar to right/left click context menu). So I have used Kendo Grid's Cell Template to show the link in the grid cell that shows the dropdown menu upon clicking (see code sample attached). Issue is that the link shows and clicking on it shows the dropdown menu as well, but the menu gets hidden inside the row height.